# Differentiability of solution of a non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a non-linear differential equation $y'(t)=y^2 + t$. Find the maximum number of times the solution $y(t)$ is differentiable for $t\in R$.

- I know that most of the linear DE has solutions containing elementary functikns like $$e^x,~ \sin(x),~\cos(x)$$ etc. But do not really know about non linear case. Also, I do not know a direct method to seek the solution. Kindly help.

Comment: @coffeemath I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the right hand side of the given DE is a real  analytic function of the variables $y$ and $t$ it follows from general principles that any solution is real analytic, in particular $C^\infty$, on its domain of definition.

The $C^\infty$ part can be proven by induction: If $\phi: t\mapsto y(t)$ is a solution on some interval $J$ then $\phi$ is differentiable, hence continuous on $J$. Assume now that $\phi\in C^r(J)$ for some $r\geq0$. Then $t\mapsto \phi^2(t)+t$ is in $C^r$ as well. The DE then tells you that $\phi'\in C^r$, which in turn implies $\phi\in C^{r+1}$.

The given DE is of Riccati type, and has no elementary solutions.

Comment: thanks a lot...@Christian Batter

Answer (score 1):

Since the equation itself contains y', y must be at least once differentiable.

Now, differentiate both sides of the equation: $(y'(t))'= (y^2+ t)'$ so $y''(t)= 2yy'+ 1$.  Since y is differentiable, yy' exists so y is at least twice differentiable.  Differentiate that: $y'''(t)= 2y'^2+ 2yy''$.  Since y is twice differentiable, $2y'^2+ 2yy'$ exists- y is at least three times differentiable.

Keep doing that.  Do you ever reach a point where the next derivative does not exist?